# React component render call loaded by webpacker isn't rendering anything after Rails3 to Rails4 upgrade

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpack, rubygems, sprockets

I'm struggling with integrating React into my Rails4 application(just upgraded from Rails3).  I'm sort of at a standstill here because I'm getting no console errors and the React component is being "rendering" onto the page with nothing processed in the `render` call.

What I've done:

1. Add `react-rails` and `webpacker` to my Gemfile
2. Followed [Gracefully integrate Reactjs with Ruby on Rails in SaaS Applications](https://blog.kiprosh.com/integrating-react-with-rails/) 
    a. `bundle install`

    b. `rake webpacker:install`

```
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ webpack-dev-server@4.13.3
info All dependencies
└─ webpack-dev-server@4.13.3
Done in 21.05s.
Webpacker successfully installed
```

c. `rake webpacker:install:react`

```
success Saved 5 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ @babel/preset-react@7.18.6
├─ babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types@0.4.24
├─ prop-types@15.8.1
├─ react-dom@18.2.0
└─ react@18.2.0
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/preset-react@7.18.6
├─ babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types@0.4.24
├─ prop-types@15.8.1
├─ react-dom@18.2.0
└─ react@18.2.0
Done in 11.59s.
Webpacker now supports react.js
```

d. `rails generate react:install`

```
     exist  app/javascript/components
      create  app/javascript/components/.keep
      append  app/javascript/packs/application.js
   identical  app/javascript/packs/server_rendering.js
```

3. Add `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` to my `application.html.erb` file
4. `rails g react:component HelloWorld greeting:string`

    a. Which creates the component at `app/assets/javascript/HelloWorld.js`
5. `rails g controller greetings hello`

```
      create  app/controllers/greetings_controller.rb
       route  get 'greetings/hello'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/greetings
      create    app/views/greetings/hello.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/greetings_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/greetings_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/greetings.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/greetings.scss
```

5. Place the `react_component` helper call inside of `hello.html.erb` (for greetings)

```
<h1>Greetings#hello</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/greetings/hello.html.erb</p>
<%= react_component("HelloWorld", { greeting: "Hello from react-rails." }) %>
```

6. Visiting the route at `localhost:3000/greetings/hello` gives me:

[image]

What am I missing here?

## Extra information:

`webpacker.yml`

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .jsx
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

`rake webpacker:info`

```
Ruby: ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
Rails: 4.2.11.3
Webpacker: 4.3.0
Node: v14.21.3
Yarn: 1.22.19
```

`app/assets/javascript/packs/application.js`

```
var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true);
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs");
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext);
```

`babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  var validEnv = ['development', 'test', 'production']
  var currentEnv = api.env()
  var isDevelopmentEnv = api.env('development')
  var isProductionEnv = api.env('production')
  var isTestEnv = api.env('test')

  if (!validEnv.includes(currentEnv)) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please specify a valid `NODE_ENV` or ' +
        '`BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", ' +
        '"test", and "production". Instead, received: ' +
        JSON.stringify(currentEnv) +
        '.'
    )
  }

  return {
    presets: [
      isTestEnv && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          targets: {
            node: 'current'
          },
          modules: 'commonjs'
        },
        '@babel/preset-react'
      ],
      (isProductionEnv || isDevelopmentEnv) && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          forceAllTransforms: true,
          useBuiltIns: 'entry',
          corejs: 3,
          modules: false,
          exclude: ['transform-typeof-symbol']
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/preset-react',
        {
          development: isDevelopmentEnv || isTestEnv,
          useBuiltIns: true
        }
      ]
    ].filter(Boolean),
    plugins: [
      'babel-plugin-macros',
      '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
      isTestEnv && 'babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring',
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        {
          loose: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
        {
          useBuiltIns: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        {
          helpers: false,
          regenerator: true,
          corejs: false
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
        {
          async: false
        }
      ],
      isProductionEnv && [
        'babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types',
        {
          removeImport: true
        }
      ]
    ].filter(Boolean)
  }
}
```

`Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.11.3'
# A Ruby wrapper for Linux inotify, using FFI
gem 'rb-inotify', :require => false
# FSEvents API with Signals catching (without RubyCocoa)
gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1'
# A Ruby wrapper for Windows Kernel functions for monitoring the specified directory or subtree
gem 'rb-fchange', :require => false
# The Ruby interface to the PostgreSQL RDBMS
gem 'pg', '~> 0.17.1'
# Annotates Rails/ActiveRecord Models, routes, fixtures
gem 'annotate', '2.6.0'
# Flexible authentication solution for Rails with Warden
gem 'devise', '3.4.0'
# Authorization solution for Rails which is decoupled from user roles
gem 'cancan'
# Markdown to (X)HTML parser
gem 'redcarpet'
# An interface between Ruby and ImageMagick.
gem 'rmagick'
# Structured (X)HTML/XML templating engine.
gem 'haml'
# Extension of CSS, adding nested rules, variables, mixins, selector inheritance,
gem 'sass'
# Provides jQuery and the jQuery-ujs driver
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Process incoming emails with a simple routing DSL
gem 'mailman'
gem 'mailman-rails'
# Cron jobs in Ruby
gem 'whenever', :require => false
# ActiveRecord backend for Delayed::Job
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
# Ruby debugging companion; pretty print Ruby objects to visualize structure
gem 'awesome_print'
# Implements a PDF parser conforming as much as possible to the PDF specification from Adobe
gem 'pdf-reader'
# Documentation generation tool
gem 'yard'
# A module for encoding and decoding (X)HTML entities.
gem 'htmlentities'
# Provides both resource oriented interfaces and API clients for AWS services.
gem "aws-sdk", "< 2.0"
gem 'aws-partitions', '~> 1.748.0'
# Web server
gem 'thin'
# ruby wrapper for posting to slack webhooks
gem 'slack-notifier', '1.5.1'
# Adds support for creating state machines for attributes on any Ruby class
gem "state_machines-activerecord"
# Simple (but safe) token authentication for Rails apps or API with Devise.
gem 'simple_token_authentication'
# Used to send messages via email/slack upon exceptions thrown
gem 'exception_notification', '4.1.1'
# Used for managing uploads within Ruby Models
gem "paperclip"
# SOAP client
# Latest Savon version to not depend on {Nokogiri: Ruby 2.5}
gem 'savon', '0.9.1'
# A generalized Rack framework for multiple-provider authentication.
gem 'omniauth'
# AREL integrated into Active Record
gem "squeel"
# Provides an easy way to wrap existing ruby scripts to be run as a daemon and to be controlled by simple start/stop/restart commands - used with delayed_jobs
gem "daemons"
# Meant to serve the use-case of connecting, querying and iterating over results to Microsoft SQL Server
gem "tiny_tds", '1.3.0'
# AWS S3 integration
gem "aws-sdk-s3"
# Supports mass assignment until Rails 5.0
gem 'protected_attributes'
# Re-enables deprecated finder methods
gem "activerecord-deprecated_finders"
# REST on Rails
gem 'activeresource'
# Re-enables respond_with/respond_to
gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'
# # Asset compilation strategy
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.3.0'
# React in Rails
gem 'react-rails'

group :production, :staging do
  # Call JavaScript code and manipulate JavaScript objects from Ruby. Call Ruby code and manipulate Ruby objects from JavaScript.
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  # Lets you run JavaScript code from Ruby.
  gem 'execjs'
  # Faster process spawning
  gem 'posix-spawn'
end

group :test do
  # TODO looking to replace with the default testing suite of rails 4.2
  # Adds Minitest as the default testing library in Rails
  gem 'minitest-rails', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.1'
  # Used to ensure a clean state for testing in conjunction with minitest
  gem 'database_cleaner-active_record'
  # Rails performance testing helpers
  gem 'rails-perftest'
  # General Purpose cryptography
  gem 'openssl', '2.0.2'
end

group :development do
  # Code profiler for Ruby
  gem 'ruby-prof', '0.18.0'
  # Client Side profiling, DB profiling and Server profiling.
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '2.0.2'
  # Supporting gem for Rails Panel
  gem 'meta_request'
  # Used for advanced debugging in development environment
  gem "binding_of_caller"
  # Turns off Rails asset pipeline log.
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  # Help to kill N+1 queries and unused eager loading.
  gem "bullet"
  # IRB alternative with powerful introspection capabilities
  gem 'pry'
  # Turns Pry into a primitive debugger
  gem 'pry-nav'
  # Enables irb console to be used in the view, actively debugging the page on error.
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

group :assets do
  # Sass adapter for the Rails asset pipeline.
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 5.0'
  # CoffeeScript adapter for the Rails asset pipeline.
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.1'
  # jQuery UI's JavaScript, CSS, and image files packaged for the asset pipeline
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  # Recompiles changed assets for the asset pipeline
  gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails4'
  # Select2 with Rails asset pipeline
  gem "select2-rails"
  # Minifies JavaScript files by wrapping UglifyJS to be accessible in Ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
end
```